# re stylign anchor tag to remove jerky scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html page with a form and a anchor tag at the end of the page that scroll when clicked scrolls back to the top of the page with a smooth scroll implemented using javascript.

The problem I am facing is that the scroll is jerky. There is a slight jerk before it proceeds to scroll. This doesn't happen in jsfiddle though.

I am not sure if it is because of the anchor tag or JS. Is there a way I can fix it by changing/styling anchor tag to regular text. I believe the problem is something to do with the anchor tag. I am not sure though.

Thanks

```
alert("Scroll triggered");
$('a[href="#register"]').click(function(){
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 1000);    
$('input#Name_First').focus();
 });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/co1ot6ru/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS fiddle uses the code

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 1000, function(){    
    $('input#Name_First').focus();
});
```

If you change it to the code provided in the question

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 1000);   
$('input#Name_First').focus();
```

It also jerks;

This shows that the issue is - the "focus" needs to be in the callback for the animation.

Comment: Yup! You were right. focus was the culprit. I removed it it works without the jerk. I am figuring out a way to have in the callback.

Comment: I am pretty new to java script animation. I am not sure how to go about it.